# How to use APScheduler to automatically load new data in a Dash Application

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, plotly-dash, apscheduler

**Problem Description**

I want to use [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/userguide.html) in order to automatically load new data for a [Dash](https://dash.plotly.com/) application. Let's work with the following tangible example: the process of loading new data is proxied by generating a timestamp, which is supposed to be updated regularly, and then shown by the application.

**Desired Output**

After running the file and visiting http://127.0.0.1:8050/, it should read `2022-07-11 21:09:40`, which is updated 10 seconds later to `2022-07-11 21:09:50`, and so on.

**Actual Output**

The application only shows the first timestamp, but is not updated.

**Code**

```
# packages
import dash
from dash import html
import datetime
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler


# proxy for loading new data
def load_data():
    global timestamp
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
    return timestamp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #initialize
    timestamp = load_data()

    # Scheduler
    sched = BackgroundScheduler()
    sched.add_job(func=load_data, trigger='interval', seconds=10)
    sched.start()

    # Dash App
    app = dash.Dash(__name__)
    app.layout = html.Div(html.Label(str(timestamp)))
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Any help would be gratefully acknowledged!

Comment: The interval component https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/interval could help you to trigger the callback which updates the data. See also https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates

Comment: Hi @Carlos,
thanks a lot for your suggestion. I think your proposed solution would work. Yet, I am hesitant to follow that approach since my `load_data` process is quite extensive and should not be part of a callback. For that reason, it would be best to have the `load_data` (with low frequency) process governed by the APScheduler and have various callbacks from within the app in high frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `apscheduler` results are not able to trigger components.
The normal pattern is storing the result at a given location, e.g. the global variable in your case, and use the interval component to poll the data and serve as trigger for other components.

Example:

```py
import dash
from dash import html, dcc
import datetime
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

# proxy for loading new data
def load_data():
    global timestamp
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
    return timestamp

#initialize
timestamp = load_data()

# Scheduler
sched = BackgroundScheduler()
sched.add_job(func=load_data, trigger='interval', seconds=1)
sched.start()

# Dash App
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Interval(
        id='interval-component',
        interval=250, # in milliseconds
        n_intervals=0
    ),
    dcc.Store(id="memory-store"),
    html.Label(id="label")
])

# callbacks
@app.callback(Output('memory-store', 'data'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
def poll_data(n):
    return {"timestamp": timestamp}

@app.callback(Output('label', 'children'),
              Input('memory-store', 'data'))
def update_page(data):
    return data.get("timestamp", "-")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Note: here I use a store component to place the data from the polling callback and another callback to update the page, in order to separate the logic of bringing the data into dash triggers and using it at the desired places on the dashboard.